# From where does gdb take the code lines?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gdb, dwarf

When I compile a program with -g and get a core dump I can use `gdb` to read the executable and the core dump to debug the situation the program run into before it crashed. One of the features `gdb` offers is the `list` option, it is possible to list the source code which was compiled using the executable and the core dump. I used `strings -a` with the executable and the core dump and I couldn't find even one `if` or `for` statements while I'm sure the code has plenty of them. So where does the code is coming from? I compile the code on one computer and run it on different one, so the source code is not available on the computer where the core dump is generated, and it doesn't seem to be inside the executable or the core dump. Any suggestions? I really want to print all the source code from the executable and from the core dump, is it possible? I mean without running `gdb`, I'm sure it is possible to write a script which uses gdb and that can list the entire code but I'm interested in doing it myself without `gdb` because I want to understand from where the source code is taken how it is formatted, I want o know as much as possible about it.

Comment: There are a number of different formats for debugging information; how you would access it directly would depend on which format was being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line information is located in the `.debug_line` DWARF sections of the executable:

```
$readelf -wL ./a.out 
Decoded dump of debug contents of section .debug_line:

CU: bla.c:
File name                            Line number    Starting address
bla.c                                          2            0x4004b6
bla.c                                          3            0x4004ba
bla.c                                          4            0x4004bf
```

This sections maps instruction pointer addresses to line numbers in a given file.

In order to find the content of the file, you need to be able to finds the relevant source file. If you move/rename the source file, GDB will not be able to print the source code:

```
mv bla.c bla2.c
gdb ./a.out
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
(gdb) list
1       in bla.c
```

The `.debug_info` DWARF sections has some information on the path where the source file was when it was compiled which may be used to find the relevant file:

```
$objdump -Wi -wa ./a.out 

./a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64
./a.out

Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0x4e (32-bit)
   Version:       4
   Abbrev Offset: 0x0
   Pointer Size:  8
 : Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
       DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): GNU C 4.9.1 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g
       DW_AT_language    : 1        (ANSI C)
       DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x59): bla.c
       DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x31): /home/myself/temp/bla
       DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x4004b6
       DW_AT_high_pc     : 0xb
       DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0
 : Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
       DW_AT_external    : 1
       DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x2c): main
       DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
       DW_AT_decl_line   : 2
       DW_AT_type        : 
       DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x4004b6
       DW_AT_high_pc     : 0xb
       DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c         (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
       DW_AT_GNU_all_call_sites: 1
 : Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_base_type)
       DW_AT_byte_size   : 4
       DW_AT_encoding    : 5        (signed)
       DW_AT_name        : int
 : Abbrev Number: 0
```

Each `DW_TAG_compile_unit` has information about the source file name and path which is used to find the relevant source file.

I you want to do it all by yourself, you should probably read some relevant parts of the [DWARF specifications](http://www.dwarfstd.org/Download.php) and use a library such as libdw (which is a part of [elfutils](https://fedorahosted.org/elfutils/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved me few days of running in circles. Happy new year @ysdx!